# Set input type hidden value with jQuery using closest() method

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to set the value of the `input[type=hidden]` that is closest to the tag `<img src="off.png">` or `<img src="on.png">`

Is there something I don't get. Any suggestions?

```js
$(document).on('click', 'img.toggle', function() {
  var atr = $(this).attr("src");
  var ths = $(this);

  if (atr == "off.png") {
    $(this).attr("src", "on.png");
    $("input[type='hidden']").closest(ths).val("on");
  }

  if (atr == "on.png") {
    $(this).attr("src", "off.png");
    $("input[type='hidden']").closest(ths).val("off");
  }

  console.log($("input[type='hidden']").closest(ths).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Instalacja elektryczna:</legend>
  <div class="separator">
    Posiadana instalacja 3 fazowa 
    <input class="xForm" type="hidden" name="instalacja_trojfazowa" />
    <img class="toggle" src="off.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="separator">
    Instalacja posiada "Neutral" 
    <input class="xForm" type="hidden" name="posiada_neutral" />
    <img class="toggle" src="off.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="separator">
    Instalacja posiada "Uziemienie" 
    <input class="xForm" type="hidden" name="posiada_uziemienie" />
    <img class="toggle" src="off.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="separator">
    Napięcie na 1 fazę +-10%
    <input class="xForm" type="text" name="napiecie_nafaze" />
  </div>
  <div class="separator"> 
    Nie znam tych parametrów 
    <input class="xForm" type="hidden" name="nie_znamparel" />
    <img class="toggle" src="off.png" />
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Try change `$("input[type='hidden']").closest(ths)` to `ths.parent().find("input[type='hidden']")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your structute you need to use [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) , becouse `img` and `input:hidden` are at the same level, [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) is looking in the parents and returns the first match

```js
$(document).on('click', 'img.toggle', function () {
    var atr = $(this).attr("src");
    var ths = $(this);
    var sibling = $(this).siblings('input:hidden')
    if (atr == "off.png") {
        $(this).attr("src", "on.png");
        $(sibling).val("on");
    }
    if (atr == "on.png") {
        $(this).attr("src", "off.png");
        $(sibling).val("off");
    }

    alert($(sibling).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Instalacja elektryczna:</legend>
    <div class="separator">Posiadana instalacja 3 fazowa <input class="xForm"  type="hidden" name="instalacja_trojfazowa"  /><img class="toggle" src="off.png" /></div>
    <div class="separator">Instalacja posiada "Neutral" <input class="xForm"  type="hidden" name="posiada_neutral"  /><img class="toggle" src="off.png" /></div>
    <div class="separator">Instalacja posiada "Uziemienie" <input class="xForm"  type="hidden" name="posiada_uziemienie" /><img class="toggle" src="off.png" /></div>
    <div class="separator">Napięcie na 1 fazę +-10% <input class="xForm"  type="text" name="napiecie_nafaze"  /></div>
    <div class="separator">Nie znam tych parametrów <input class="xForm"  type="hidden" name="nie_znamparel" /><img class="toggle" src="off.png" /></div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant, although the mechanism I do not understand - why does not want to work with closest ()?

Comment: @SylwesterMarć because closest is looking in parents you can do it with closest like this
`$(this).closest(".separator").find("input:hidden")`, this will find the first parent with class `separator` and search for all `input:hidden` in the div.separator. `input:hidden` is not a parent of `img.toggle` it's a sibling

Answer (score 2):

Look at the description of [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

`<input>` and `<img>` are both void elements. They can't have children. The `<img>` therefore cannot be the **ancestor** of the `<input>`.

Your elements are **siblings**.  Use the [`prev` method](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) instead.

---

Better yet, don't use JavaScript at all. Make the hidden input a checkbox and put the image in its `<label>`